# Jest: Continue testing when expected error is thrown on button click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, react-tsx, react-error-boundary

I am trying to test a React error boundary (with `react-error-boundary` library) by creating a button (to test that the code inside the library is displayed) and when clicked I want to verify that the error text is displayed, here are some screenshots

[image]
[image]

Here are the 2 files used:

- error-fallback.tsx

```tsx
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

function ErrorFallback({ error }: { error: Error; resetErrorBoundary: () => void }) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <p>Error displaying this section</p>
      <pre>{error.message}</pre>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default ErrorFallback;
```

- error-fallback.test.tsx

```tsx
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ErrorBoundary } from "react-error-boundary";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { useState } from "react";

import ErrorFallback from "./error-fallback";

const buttonText = "Throw Error";
const errorValue = "This is a test error";

const ThrowError = () => {
  throw new Error(errorValue);
};

export const ErrorFallbackTest = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const triggerError = () => setError(true);
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
      <Box sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        {error && <ThrowError />}
        <button onClick={triggerError}>{buttonText}</button>
      </Box>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

it("react boundary works", async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<ErrorFallbackTest />);

  const buttonTrigger = getByText(buttonText);

  fireEvent(buttonTrigger, new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));

  const boundaryText = getByText("Error displaying this section");
  expect(boundaryText).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(boundaryText).toBeDefined();
  expect(boundaryText).toBeVisible();
});
```

Attaching Jest error log. I am not sure which is the proper way to handle this, should I expect an error with Jest? How can I add it if the error is expected to be thrown on button click?

```sh
  ● Console
    console.error
      Error: Uncaught [Error: This is a test error]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54764497/9296982
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11098#issuecomment-523977830

```tsx
it("react boundary works", async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<ErrorFallbackTest />);

  const buttonTrigger = getByText(buttonText);

  const spy = jest.spyOn(console, "error");
  spy.mockImplementation(() => {});

  fireEvent(buttonTrigger, new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));

  const boundaryText = getByText("Error displaying this section");
  expect(boundaryText).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(boundaryText).toBeDefined();
  expect(boundaryText).toBeVisible();

  spy.mockRestore();
});
```